# Probability that after n trials the sum of values would be more than x.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

Suppose we have a bag with cards, each card has a number $2$,$3$ or $4$ on it, so sample space is $\{2, 3, 4\}$. Each sample point is equally likely (so $1/3$).
We than pick $n$ cards from the bag. What is the probability that sum of numbers on the cards will be more than $x$?

Also the overall number of cards in the bag is infinite or so high it is negligible (I suppose it doesn't matter at all in this question).
I want to find general formula, but at least solve some example would be good also, I'm kinda stuck.

So suppose we pick $12$ cards and need to find what is the probability that we will get more than $40$ if we sum all the numbers on them.

$$n=12, p=1/3, P[X\geq40]=?$$
It looks kinda like Binomial distribution, but here $X$ does not mean "number of successes obtained in $n$ trials". In fact, I don't think we have any kind of "success" here. What should I use in this case?

Comment: For the specific values at the bottom of the question, the minimum sum is $24$ and the maximum sum is $48$. Calculating the probability of each one of them, as well as those "nearby" ($25,26,46,47$), is rather easy. The more you go "towards the middle", the harder it becomes. For $P(X\geq40$), you can add up the values of $P(X=40),P(X=41),\dots,P(X=48)$. But again, some of those terms might be difficult to calculate.

Comment: Yes, of course this manual approach would work, but if the number of cards we get would be lets say 100 - then already it would take too much time to calculate by hand. I am quite sure there should be at least some simplification, because it doesn't seem like very unique problem.

Comment: As I said, I don't think that there's an easy approach for it once you go "towards the middle".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{N(2x_1+3x_2+4x_3\geq 40,x_1+x_2+x_3=n)}{N(x_1+x_2+x_3=n)}=\frac{N(2x_1+3x_2+4n-4x_1-4x_2\geq 40, x_1+x_2\leq n)}{N(x_1+x_2+x_3=n)}$$
$$=\frac{N(2x_1+x_2\leq 4n-40, x_1+x_2\leq n)}{N(x_1+x_2+x_3=n)}=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{4n-40}N(2x_1+x_2=i, x_1+x_2\leq n)}{\binom{n+3-1}{3-1}}$$
$$=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{4n-40}\sum_{x_1=0}^{[\frac{i}{2}]}N(x_2=i-2x_1\leq n-x_1)}{\binom{n+2}{2}}=\frac{\sum_{i=0}^{4n-40}\sum_{x_1=0}^{[\frac{i}{2}]}f(i,x_1)}{\binom{n+2}{2}}$$
Where $N()$ means number of possible non-negative integer answers. $x_i$, $i=1,2,3$ respectively show number of cards with 2, 3 and 4 on them in the chosen n cards. $[z]$ means biggest integer before $z$. And finally $f(i,x_1)$ is $0$ if $i-2x_1>n-x_1$ and is $1$ if $i-2x_1\leq n-x_1$.

For $n\geq 20$ this fraction is $1$ and for $n< 10$ is $0$, which is compatible with the observation since;
$$n\geq 20\Longrightarrow 2x_1+3x_2+4x_3\geq 2(x_1+x_2+x_3)=2\times n\geq 40$$ 
$$n< 10\Longrightarrow 2x_1+3x_2+4x_3\leq 4(x_1+x_2+x_3)=4\times n< 40$$

Here I wrote a Maple code to compute it. I chose it return us for values $n$ from $1$ to $20$, you can run it for different values. As you can see for $n=20$ it is $1$ and for $n$ strictly less than $10$, it is $0$.

```
f := proc (n, x, y) 
     if x-n <= y then 1 else 0 end if; 
     end proc;
for n from 1 by 1 to 20 do
    add(add(f(n, i, j), j = 0 .. floor((1/2)*i)), i = 0 .. 4*n-40))/binomial(n+2, 2);
    end do;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please exmplain this one - 2x1+3x2+4n−4x1−4x2>40? Why do you multiply the number of cards with 2 on it(x1) with the value of card with 4 on it(4)? And where does 4n mean?

Comment: @ScienceSamovar you want sum of numbers on cards be greater than 40 so first what is this sum if x_1 of the n cards be with 2 and x_2 of them be with 3 and x_3 of them be with 4? The sum will be 2x_1+3x_2+4x_3 and now we have this condition that we chose n cards so we have x_1+x_2+x_3=n so with this assumption we have x_3=n-x_1-x_2.

Comment: oh, indeed... What is [z] you wrote about? Do you mean [i/2]? What these square brackets indicate? Sorry to bother you, I getting it very slow...

Comment: @ScienceSamovar I explained my mean by the symbol [.] in general! No matter, you can ask questions as much as possible.

Comment: @ScienceSamovar the reason N(2x_1+x_2=i)=[i/2]+1 is, you have [i/2]+1 choices for x_1 (containing (x_1)=0 so I added that '+1') and when you choose a value for x_1 then x_2 has only one choice which is (i-2x_1).

Comment: ok, maybe I would need more time to grasp it completely, but I get basic idea. One more question - in denominator we need to have all possible outcomes of experiment, why it is n+3-1 over 3-1 binomial? It seems like "Possible ways to take 2 cards from 14 cards" in regular language. Why 14?

Comment: @ScienceSamovar You want to distribute n cards into 3 labels, you can do it by putting them in a line and then putting two lines at two positions between them or the position before first card or after last card. Number of cards before first line is x_1, number of cards between first and second lines is x_2 and number of cards after second line is x_3. So now lines and cards are n+2 and 2 of these are lines. So choosing 2 from n+2.

Comment: @ScienceSamovar Are you still thinking and trying to understand my answer or you got it?

Comment: yea, kinda... I did a quick check with simple case and the answers didn't match up exactly... or maybe I simply did a mistake somewhere, haven't got enough time to think about it thoroughly. I'm planning to go to probability/math teacher at my university to ask more about it and I'm going to add info in original post if I would find any. I will mark you answer if you want, sorry, had much things going on at the moment... Hopefully I will bring something useful also(laymen explanation at least) in couple of days.

Comment: @ScienceSamovar the problem was that $2x_1+3x_2+4x_3\geq 40,x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ imply $2x_1+3x_2+4n-4x_1-4x_2\geq 40$ but not its reverse so for having equality I had to add one of the former conditions, I chose $x_1+x_2+x_3=n$ but as $x_3$ can be determined uniquely from $x_1$ and $x_2$ then I only need to put a condition on those two so I used $x_1+x_2\leq n$ (as $x_3\geq 0)$.

Comment: @ScienceSamovar I really enjoyed myself from what I wrote like a small kid! So I think not only answering, I found all values for you too ^_^ How is it now? For example look at case $n=10$, there are 66 ways to do your experiment but only in one case which all 10 cards be with number 4 is a win, so 1/66!

Comment: hi again, thank you for addition to you answer, I checked it(with more simple example) and yeah, it kinda works, great :) Though I am a little bit slow on grasping formula derivation, but that's all because I don't have much time, have many things on my shoulders now, ugh :( But I'll get it eventually, just need to sit and think for 30 minutes :)